# Runnig two instances of a script in forever.js

Tags: node.js, forever, forever-monitor

Is there a way to run two or more instances of the same node script in forever.js? If not what is the best tool used for that?

Comment: You can use forever from within a node script. Refer to the documentation: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best tool (at the moment) to run same node process forever is [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2).

`npm i pm2 -g`

`pm2 start app.js -i 2`

This will run two instances of he same app even if your app opens the same port. `pm2` uses [clustering](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to route network connections to both instances of the app. You don't even need to bother about clustering, just open any ports and it will work.

Comment: The license is not the same as forever.js so I can see why people want to do multiple instances by using forever

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just call `forever start <your script>` twice. I just tried that and it works.

Comment: this is correct, but if you are running a server, the port would be dupplicate and throw an error EADDRINUSE error

Answer (score 0):

You need to install minimist package, then in app.js write logic to invoke ip and port dynamically from command argument.
Mention all your app in a json file and then run that json file by forever start command.

Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263292/10057582