# starting node forever script with PORT=XXXX

Tags: node.js, npm, forever

when running node in command over a specific port, I'd start the app this way:

```
PORT=1234 node app.js
```

how do I pass the port to the `forever` command? no matter what I try, it seems to not want to work.

I've tried:

- passing the port as an arg: `forever start app.js 1234`
- passing the port declaration as an arg: `forever start app.js PORT=1234`

Comment: how do you stop it with command line in windows?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
PORT=1234 forever start app.js
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding     `export PORT=1234` to app.js
Then just run with     `forever start app.js`

Answer (score 2):

```
PORT=1234 forever start app.js
```

Unfortunately that didn't work for me, so I tried this and it works:

```
forever start app.js --port 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node forever, you can create a forever.json file in your root directory and mention all your ports there in that json file inside an array. Example:

### forever.json

```
[
   {
      "uid": "app1",
      "append": true,
      "watch": true,
      "script": "server.js",
      "sourceDir": "D:\\DEVELOPEMENT\\workshop",
      "args": ["--port", "8081", "--ip", "127.0.0.1"]
    },
    {

        "uid": "app2",
        "append": true,
        "watch": true,
        "script": "server.js",
        "sourceDir": "D:\\DEVELOPEMENT\\workshop" ,
        "args": ["--port", "8082", "--ip", "127.0.0.1"]
      },

      {

        "uid": "app3",
        "append": true,
        "watch": true,
        "script": "server.js",
        "sourceDir": "D:\\DEVELOPEMENT\\workshop" ,
        "args": ["--port", "8083", "--ip", "127.0.0.1"]
       }
]
```

Provide your source directory and script(app.js/server.js).

Now run all the above 3 apps in different ports by command ***forever start forever.json***

But node forever pass ip and ports through command line to our program. So to get values from process.argv we need minimist package of node. install minimist and then write your app.js as below to provide ip and port dynamically through command(Forever will do it automatically).

### server.js / app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const parseArgs = require('minimist') (process.argv.slice(2))
const IP = parseArgs.ip || "127.0.0.1"
const PORT = parseArgs.port || 8000


app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Server running on " + IP  + ":" + PORT)
})

console.log("START ", IP+" :",PORT)
app.listen(PORT, IP)

module.exports = app;
```

Now run **forever start forever.json** and check all the port described in forever.json.

Comment: @FaizanRupani  in window `CNTRL + C` or if you want to kill process then type this command -

`$ Taskkill /IM node.exe /F or 
$ forever stop server.js`